# how to delete particular column value alone in postgresql database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table. The table name is employee. I used below query.

```
delete department,name,bloodgroup from employee where employeeid=2;
```

But I am not able to delete this record alone. It is showing error. And I don't want to use update statement.

Comment: It can not be standart sql. Normally Delete command cant do this.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `update` statement? It's the only way to set specific column values to null

Comment: As others have pointed out, using SQL you can delete rows, but you can't delete values. Instead, you can (possibly) update values to NULL or to some other sensible value, such as zero.

Answer (score 34):

You can't delete single column entries with the `delete` SQL command. Only complete rows.

You can use the `update` command for that:

```
update employee 
set department = null, name = null, bloodgroup = null
where employeeid=2;
```

Comment: Or, if the OP actually wants to delete the whole record...  `DELETE employee WHERE employeeid = 2`

Comment: @Dems: `DELETE FROM employee ...`

Comment: What if department has a not-null constraint e.g.?

Comment: @s.k: If a record without a department is not allowed by design then you can not set it null. That is why the restriction was made by the one creating the table design

Comment: Right. And what if you want to replace the value by its default value instead of setting it to `null`? (let's assume you don't really know its default value - or, if you cannot set it in a general way that would be universal for any data type, what would you do to know its default value? Some special data types such as arrays may have default values which may look strange to newcomers)

Comment: @s.k: There is no universal default value. Maybe you should ask a specific question about your problem with some example data.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution won't work until NOT NULL constraint is dropped(removed) to do this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee;
ALTER COLUMN department DROP NOT NULL;
```

After this You can UPDATE the table as above:

```sql
UPDATE employee SET department = null WHERE employeeid =2;
```

Hope this one helps Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot DELETE a particular column value in SQL, we can UPDATE it.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete a particular column full value of a table in the database using this command.

UPDATE 'table_name' SET 'column_name' = NULL;

Using this command you can clear all the values of a column to null